# Getting innacurate google search results from google APIs

Tags: c#, ajax, json, api, google-custom-search

What do I have?

- Google Account.
- Simple API Key access.
- I have created a Custom Search Engine, I've set **Search the entire web but emphasize included sites** in it, and I have removed all the links from **Sites to search** section (so that it searched the entire web, and it's not restricted to a certain website).
- From the Custom Search Engine I got **CX** (search engine ID).

If I try this command:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[MY_API_KEY]&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=intitle:%22crazy+stink%22
```

(the CX is provided by google as an example here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest, but I get the same results if I set my own CX).

Results:

```
{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
 "queries": {
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - intitle:\"crazy stink\"",
    "totalResults": "0",
    "searchTerms": "intitle:\"crazy stink\"",
    "count": 10,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve"
   }
  ]
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.35068,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.35",
  "totalResults": "0",
  "formattedTotalResults": "0"
 }
}
```

If you test this out, you can see that this will give you 0 results, however if you perform a Google search for the same query, you'll get approx. 35 results: https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle%3A%22crazy+stink%22

This is the main reason why I'm asking for assistance. In my project I need all of these results, if normal Google search gives 35 results, I need to get these 35 results as well.

I need this for my C# project, however I don't really care in which format do I get the results (JSON, XML, etc...)

I plan on enabling billing feature, and exceeding the "Free" limitations of 100 queries/day I currently have. However before I do that I need to have fully functional facility (which I don't at the moment).

---

An additional note:
Even with the free AJAX Api: [http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=1&rsz=large&q=intitle:%22crazy+stink%22](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=1&rsz=large&q=intitle%3a%22crazy+stink%22) I get 0 results (you can test this one out without the API key).
Results:

```
{"responseData": {"results":[],"cursor":{"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d1\u0026hl\u003den\u0026q\u003dintitle:%22crazy+stink%22","searchResultTime":"0.10"}}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

Any ideas, suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: We don't have a C# library yet, but I would try [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com), you should be able to get better results.

Answer (score 1):

With this api https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest, You have to give some sites to search, If you didn't provide the sites to search here(https://www.google.com/cse/all), It will not show you the results. At least put one site to search, or many sites to search. Your wanted Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. 
https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/
It only search entire web

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With this tutorial https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en I thought I could search the entire web (but this tutorial also say that I won't be able to get the same results as I do when I use Google Web Search normally). Another bad thing with this is that this works only for free/basic CSEs (so I wouldn't be able to do this if I become "billing enabled" user).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue,
after research i found that i didnt provide sites in search engine which i created
so i provide www.google.com as a site in search engine page
here is the link to add site in your search engine

https://www.google.com/cse/setup/basic?cx={your search engine id}

after executing above link with your search engine id you will get your search engine page
then go into "**Basics**" tab in which go into "**site to search**" section then **Add** site
for me i used **www.google.com**

and my issue get resolved :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this, and I got 1 result this time. This is still far from those 35 results I get when I search Google normally.

Comment: you can provide num=35 as a parameter into api so you will get 35 results but by defaults it shows 10 results how you are getting 1 result anyways just do on trial n error basis hope u will get solution best luck